How to jump to next element once match has been found in a for loop?
Python beginner here. In a list such as:
lst = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]

One pair would be (1,1) , (2,2) , (3,3), etc. When this happens it should count as ONE pair.
(1,2) , (2,3), or (3,4) is not a pair.
In this list there are 6 pairs. I want to loop through the list using a for loop to find how many times a pair occurs and when a pair is found, i want to jump to the next sequence.
For example, when starting we immediately have a pair:
[1,1]

So I want the loop to now continue reading the list from
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]

This is to avoid over-counting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
This is what I have so far:
two_pairs = 0
for c in lst:
    if lst[c] == lst[c+1]:
        c += 2
        two_pairs += 1


sum(a == b for a, b in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])) ?

c is a list element, not index. lst[c] makes no sense. I think you meant for c in range(0, len(lst)-1, 2):

looks like you want to take to values at a time? itertools.batched(lst, 2) should help? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched)

And c += 2 has no effect, since the for loop reassigns the variable from the range, it doesn't use the previous value.

This has nothing to do with sorting.

@njzk2: That won't work.

@AndrejKesely: Please post that as an answer including an explanation of how it works.

Not sure how you want it counted. If one 2 is removed from the example input, would the answer still be 6? Or would it be 4?

A simpler example: What should the result be for lst = [1,2,2,3,3,4,4]?

@ScottHunter we're probably understanding the question differently.

@njzk2: Then go ahead and post a solution using batched.

In your answer you are looping on the value of the list item instead of the position,
you can use a solution like this
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

two_pairs = 0
i = 0

while i < len(lst) - 1:
    if lst[i] == lst[i + 1]:
        two_pairs += 1
        i +=1
    i += 1  

print(two_pairs)


There is an issue with the answer posted by Jamal. Take, for example, this case [1,2,2,3,3] looping by a step of 2 will miss the (2,2) pair

If you have an issue with Jamal's answer, you should post it as a comment there, not in your own answer.

I don't even have enough reputation to comment on other's answers, that's why I didn't comment there

You have reputation 53, that's enough for comments I think.

When I posted my answer it wasn't enough, it became 53 when you commented on my answer

"There is an issue with the answer posted by Jamal." I think there's a bit of ambiguity in the question about that. I think it can be read both ways

If you want to improve someone's answer, you should comment on it, but if you want to post an alternative to someone's answer, a comment is not necessary. Instead, it would be more useful to explain in your answer what you have improved in comparison to others.

The main issue goes back to your loop. If you correct, the other part of code is right.
two_pairs = 0

for c in range(0, len(lst)-1, 2):
  if lst[c] == lst[c+1]:
        #c += 2 as loop counter is 2 so I commented this line.
        two_pairs += 1

print(two_pairs)


c += 2 is useless, since it gets overwritten.
